# Replace attr of wordpress post images

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I moved a wordpress site, but I have many posts with the following path for images: `http://www.example.com/media/76897/tips-for-keeping-your-chips-from-getting-crushed-header.jpg`

backup images are in the folder: `wp-content/uploads/blog/assets/`

example backup image: `http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/blog/assets/76897/tips-for-keeping-your-chips-from-getting-crushed-header.jpg`

I tried this place with jquery, but did not succeed.

Jquery

```
$('.wsContentAndSideBar .wsContent img').attr('src', function (i, src) {
    return 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/blog/assets/76897/' + src.split('/')[1];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the Wordpress plugin [Search Regex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/).  Be sure to back up your database before you commit any replacements. [image]

If you really want to use jquery here's code that'll work for you:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('.wsContentAndSideBar .wsContent img').each(function() {
          var oldsrc = $(this).attr('src');
          $(this).attr('src', oldsrc.replace('http://www.example.com/media/', 'http://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/blog/assets/'));
          });
      });
```

[jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/zn3wygyb/6/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use this WP plugin for this URL Replacing 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/better-search-replace/

if you want to use jQuery then you can use this:

```
$('.wsContentAndSideBar .wsContent img').attr('src','http://newimageurl');
```